# синтаксическая ошибка в коде С# | webclient

Tags: c#

В коде нету никаких ошибкой, но когда запускаю релиз, то выдает данную ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            /*wc.DownloadFile
                ("https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf",
                @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\dlc.rpf"); // paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf*/

            /*
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
                //Catalog = @"D:\"; */

                Console.WriteLine("Введите тип револьера.");
                string text = Console.ReadLine();
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(text);

                switch (x)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Тип револьера 1.");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Тип револьера 2.");
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        Console.WriteLine("Тип револьера 3.");
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Тип револьера 4.");
                        break;


                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Неверный тип.");
                        break;
                }

                if (x == 1)
                {
                    
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Револьер " + x + "Скачан");
                    wc.DownloadFile
                    ("https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_1/dlc.rpf",
                    @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\exmaple\1"); // paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf*/

                }

                if (x == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Револьер " + x + " Скачан"); // https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf
                    /*
                    wc.DownloadFile
                    ("https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf",
                    @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\exmaple\2");*/
            }

                if (x == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Револьер " + x + "Скачан");
                }

                if (x == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Револьер " + x + "Скачан");
                }






            /*File.Exsi*/
        }
```

Comment: Ну так ошибку прочитай...

Comment: Это не синтаксическая ошибка! Исправьте заголовок. И уберите оттуда C# и webclient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите от имени Администратора :-)

Но в целом - проблема в том что у приложения нету доступа к файлам. Как решать - зависит от ваших целей

Comment: Добрый день. Добавил в проект файл манифеста, выбрал вместо asInvoke requireadministrator, но также появляется ошибка